# Dates appear as year 1900 on graph

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Scatter plot

[image]

and this takes the data from this table

[image]

and for some reason on the graph the dates appear as year 1900 when in my table they are not shown that way. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you change the formatting on one of the date cells to number?

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that every single data point is entered in as a date without typos. I found one cell that was missing a "/" which made the graph display the axis as numbers instead of dates.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the format of the axis, by double clicking on it, select Axis Options and under section Number make sure you have the right format. Should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I have it formatted as date but it still shows as year 1900

Comment: the other thing you can check is that  the X axis is populated with the right series. Right click on the chart and select "Select Data" and you will see which is the series for the X axis, if necessary, you can change it by click it on edit.

Comment: no idea of what was happening but once I told it to not select the column tittles it worked, otherwise it would show me random years for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out one of my dates was mis-typed (31/09/2022 instead of 30/09/2022). So it was the problem that Brian pointed out in my case. A tip for finding bad dates that I used:

- change all the dates in the column to 'general' format
- scroll down the column to see if anything still looks like a date, it's probably a date with a typo which can't be translated into number of days since 00/01/1900 (44834 = 30/09/2022 for example, but there is no translation for my mistyped 31/09/2022 because it isn't a real day so Excel treats it as text and it stays the same)
- once I fixed the bad date the graph worked as it should treating the dates as dates instead of sequential numbers formatted as 01/01/1900, 02/01/1900 etc.